# Returning Zero in an expression rather than just leaving it blank

Tags: reporting-services, expression, percentage, iif

I have this expression that works out a percentage of what data is lost. Works fine but when results are 0 it show nothing but the % sign, What do I need to add to the below expression to show a zero rather than just blank?

```
=format(sum(Fields!CountBEFORE.Value-Fields!CountAFTER.Value)/sum(Fields!CountBEFORE.Value)*100, "#.##") & "%"
```

Comment: Cheers works! Added this now showing 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
=format(sum(Fields!CountBEFORE.Value-
Fields!CountAFTER.Value)/sum(Fields!CountBEFORE.Value)*100, "0.##") & "%"
```

Let me know if this helps.